org.springframework.data.repository.ListCrudRepository not found
I'm trying to migrate Spring Data JPA repositories for Spring Boot 3.
Full code example:
https://github.com/rcbandit111/ListCrudRepository_poc
Example:
@Transactional
@Repository
public interface AdditionalDocumentRepository extends JpaRepository<AdditionalDocumentEntity, Long> {

  List<AdditionalDocumentEntity> findByLabelAsc(String id);
}

During compilation I get error:
ListCrudRepository_poc\src\main\java\com\corp\unit\testing\config\repository\AdditionalDocumentRepository.java:13: error: cannot access ListCrudRepository
public interface AdditionalDocumentRepository extends JpaRepository<AdditionalDocumentEntity, Long> {
                                                      ^
  class file for org.springframework.data.repository.ListCrudRepository not found

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Generally mixing incompatible versions of jars. As you are using Spring Boot you should use only spring-boot-starter-data-jpa nothing else.

hm... Which jar I need to remove?

The org.springframework.data one. That is incompatible and not needed. Tip replace the testing ones you have with spring-boot-starter-test saves you 2 testing dependencies (and the risk of including incompatible ones). Remove the jakarta.servlet one as well as that is already part of spring-boot-starter-web.

I removed implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.7.14' and I get missing dependency for import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;

Which is unrelated. Feels like you are "following" some sort of tutorial or copy/pasting code. There is no Spring Cloud dependency in your list of dependencies so that annotation will not be resolved. But that has nothing to do with the removal of the dependency (in fact the removal made the compilation go further and move on to the next missing class).
